# simple caser Cipher python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Caeser Cipher program.  Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?  It is happening when i'm checking to see if the pip.index(letter) + k is greater than 25.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1, in       <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 17, in CaeserCipher
ValueError: substring not found
```

Here is my code:

```
string = 'hello'
k = 3

def CaeserCipher(string, k):

    upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower = 'abcdefgihjklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    newCipher = ''

    for letter in string:
        if letter in upper:
            if upper.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (upper.index(letter) + k) - 25
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = upper.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
        elif letter in lower:
            if upper.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (upper.index(letter) + k) - 25
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = upper.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]

    return newCipher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `elif letter in lower:` block you're accessing `upper` instead of `lower`. Looks like you copy and pasted the block of code without replacing those?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Ceasar Cypher called "rot13"; it's its own inverse.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/rot13/trunk/rot13

It's #! python3, but it should work in python2 also.

Modular arithmetic works quite well for caesar cyphers.

HTH